# Python, print is executed twice

Tags: python, printing

I've started getting into Python and neural networks using a book by Tariq Rashid. Been reading it carefully and tried, following all the steps. At one point, I should test a method, if it is executing properly. So what i did, i casted the method using print(the method has a return value). Now my problem is, it is working fine, but while the output should be a single array, they are 2 arrays with different values. When i tried debugging, the file, it also went 2 times through the print command with only 1 being there.

The only difference i have, is that i use **init** as kinda the main class(coming form java) and i created the neural network as an object in it.

Also to mention, if i execute the same procedure in the neural network file, it works fine.

```
from src2.neuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork

network = NeuralNetwork(3, 3, 3, 0.3)
print(network.query([1.0, 0.5, -1.5]))
```

This is the __ init __.py file.

```
import numpy
import scipy.special


class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) - 0.5)
        self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) - 0.5)

        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)
        pass

    def train(self):
        pass

    def query(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

        hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        return final_outputs
```

That's the file for the neural network.

Thanks in regards for every answer.

Edit:
As requested, the outputs. They aren't consistent cause of the random values.

[This is the output when printing from the __ init __ file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5ijq.png)

[This is the output when printing from the neural network file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK1lz.png)

Comment: Can you show the output and the desired output?

Comment: Added in the original post.

Comment: Please [edit] to replace the (unreadable) pictures of text with the actual text in them.

Comment: I just tried this from both the init and from a file I imported the class into and I could not replicate your error initially. But what I found was after I executed in the file where I made an import, the init file start to have errors.

Comment: Something interesting: when I removed one of the network = NeuralNetwork(3, 3, 3, 0.3) from either file, it works as intended.

Comment: Do you use an IDE or just a code editor??

Comment: And also when i try, executing the file via the Terminal, i get an error too.

Comment: I use VS Code so just a code editor. I’m not sure about your terminal issue, you’d have to post another question with details, the files worked ok when I ran them in terminal. I also wrote up an answer for this one, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two files to test this. Here is code for each.
testinit.py

```
import numpy
import scipy.special


class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.reset(inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate)
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) - 0.5)
        self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) - 0.5)

        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)
        
    
        pass
    def reset(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) - 0.5)
        self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) - 0.5)
    def train(self):
        pass

    def query(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

        hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        return final_outputs


network = NeuralNetwork(3, 3, 3, 0.3)
print(network.query([1.0, 0.5, -1.6]))
```

and importingclass.py

```
from testinit import NeuralNetwork #only consists of this line
```

The problem seems to be when you define a network in the original file and execute the print command, then you import that file into the new file "importingclass.py", even with no code, the importingclass.py will execute the print command that is defined in the original "testinit.py" file.

You can try this for yourself with the code of the files I provided and you will see that executing the "importingclass.py" file will print once with no code, provided that you use the "testinit.py" given.

Having exactly one instance of the print command in either file will produce only one print output, while having one instance of the print command in both files (for a total of two) will produce two outputs. This is the conclusion I reached.

Here is my output for the init file (with the condition that there is no print command in the file importing the class)
[image]

So, the solution is to not instantiate an object and print it in the init file that you intend to import, because this object will be created and print once from the import and once from the file using the import (I believe Python runs through the imported file's lines once).

Comment: Ok, i don't get how or why it is like that, but your solution kinda worked. So what i did now, i made a new directory(i am using PyCharm) and copied your code into it, tested it, worked fine. Then i cut the initialisation from testinit.py and pasted it in importingclass.py. Still worked fine. Tried my code again, 2 outputs. Then i changed in __ init __ "from src2.neuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork" to "from neuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork" and now i only have one output now, but PyCharm marks the line as an error(unresolved Reference 'neuralNetwork'), but executes it. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: with initialization i meant adding neuralNetwork as an object(no characters left) and the print command